# Launch firefox in headless mode using karma

Tags: angular, firefox, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I using `Angular` and 'Karma'. My conf look like this:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
            require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
            require('karma-firefox-launcher')
        ],
        client: {
            clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
        },
        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
            dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
            reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
            fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
        },
        reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['FirefoxHeadless'],
        customLaunchers: {
            'FirefoxHeadless': {
                base: 'Firefox',
                flags: [
                    '-headless',
                ],
            }
        },
        singleRun: true
    });
};
```

But, when I make command:

```
ng t
```

My Firefox browser don't start. In console I see messages:

```
 10% building 2/2 modules 0 active25 01 2019 13:59:40.553:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
25 01 2019 13:59:40.554:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser FirefoxHeadless with unlimited concurrency
25 01 2019 13:59:40.558:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Firefox                                                                                25 01 2019 14:00:40.592:WARN [launcher]: Firefox have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.  
25 01 2019 14:00:40.641:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Firefox again (1/2).
25 01 2019 14:01:40.662:WARN [launcher]: Firefox have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
25 01 2019 14:01:40.689:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Firefox again (2/2).
25 01 2019 14:01:42.605:INFO [Firefox 64.0.0 (Ubuntu 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket UQxl3SDMuWplRfbLAAAA with id 53335141
25 01 2019 14:01:52.607:WARN [Firefox 64.0.0 (Ubuntu 0.0.0)]: Disconnected (1 times), because no message in 10000 ms.
Firefox 64.0.0 (Ubuntu 0.0.0) ERROR
  Disconnected, because no message in 10000 ms.

Firefox 64.0.0 (Ubuntu 0.0.0) ERROR
  Disconnected, because no message in 10000 ms.
```

My versions:

```
"karma": "~1.7.1"
"karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.1.0"
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1"
Firefox 64.0
```

I can't understand why this is happening. Why can't the browser start? In the `Chrome` browser there is no such problem, but I need exactly the `Firefox`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved the problem. The problem was the corporate proxy server. I add in `karma.conf.js`:

```
customLaunchers: {
            'FirefoxHeadless': {
                base: 'Firefox',
                flags: [
                    '-headless',
                ],
                prefs: {
                    'network.proxy.type': 0
                }
            }
        },
```

and it worked.